# How to invoke a function generated by js_of_ocaml?

Tags: javascript, ocaml, js-of-ocaml

I am new to JavaScript, I am trying to use `js_of_ocaml`.

I first wrote a very simple `cubes.ml`:

```
let simple (a: int) =
  a + 1234
```

Then complied it:

```
ocamlfind ocamlc -package js_of_ocaml -package js_of_ocaml.syntax \
          -syntax camlp4o -linkpkg -o cubes.byte cubes.ml
```

then generated the JavaScript file:

```
js_of_ocaml cubes.byte
```

Here is the generated [cubes.js](http://paste.ubuntu.com/16258059/). Note that we could not find `1234` or function name `simple` in that file.

I have another JavaScript file `Home.js`, where I want the function `callSimple` to call what was generated in `cubes.js`. But I don't know how to write it. Could anyone help?

```
(function () {
    ...
    function callSimple(a) {
        return ???;
    };
    ...
})();
```

**Edit 1:**

I tried the solution proposed by @EdgarAroutiounian :

```
(* cubes.ml *)
let () =
  Js.Unsafe.global##.jscode := (object%js
    val simple = Js.wrap_meth_callback
        (fun a -> a + 1234)
    val speak = Js.wrap_meth_callback
        (fun () -> print_endline "hello")
  end)
```

It did compile, but it did not return the right output:
[image]

If I write in `home.js`:

```
confirm(jscode.simple(10)); // 1244 is expected
confirm(jscode.speak()); // "hello" as string is expected
```

the first line returns `function (a){return p(c,aM(b,a))}`, and the second line returns `0`. They are not what I expect.

Answer (score 6):

Here's one possible way to do it.

In our OCaml code intended to be exposed to JavaScript:

```
let () =
  Js.Unsafe.global##.jscode := (object%js
    val simple = Js.wrap_meth_callback
        (fun a -> a + 1234)
    val speak = Js.wrap_meth_callback
        (fun () -> print_endline "hello")
  end)
```

Notice that I'm using the `ppx` extension, I recommend you do so as well: this means no more `camlp4`.
You can compile that code with:

```
ocamlfind ocamlc -package js_of_ocaml.ppx -linkpkg cubes.ml -o T
js_of_ocaml T -o cubes.js
```

Then in your other file, `home.js`

```
console.log(jscode.simple(10));
console.log(jscode.speak());
```

and an `index.html` of:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
  <script src="cubes.js"></script>
  <script src="home.js"></script>
</body>
```

And that should work.

Comment: @antonrov your suggested edits are wrong and change the semantics of the post.

Comment: I guess you are referring to me... Could you, please, elaborate on your intended semantics? It would be nice if you specified what we should see in the console.

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian What you suggested did compile, but the output is not what I expect. Please see my updated OP...

Comment: @SoftTimur Can you show the full code?  What is the expected output? The 0 is coming from console.log.